# How to enable layouts for multiple(different sizes of) screen in ANDROID?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm new to android 
I want to run the android application in different screen sizes
Created

```
res/layout/layout.xml         
/res/layout-small/layout.xml   
/res/layout-large/layout.xml   
/res/layout-xlarge/layout.xml
```

four types of layout in my application

After this what I want to do 
Can any one say with example .Is there any other change want to make it in code 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your problem actually?

Comment: Is there any change I want to make in xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following ,

for small  screen

```
res/layout/layout.xml         
/res/layout-land/layout.xml
```

for large screen like tablets you can use,,

```
/res/layout-large-hdpi/layout.xml   
/res/layout-land-large-hdpi/layout.xml
```

these two representations are enough and it can fit to all devices

`layout-land` is for landscape mode for smaller devices and `layout-land-large-hdpi` for large devices,

and add these lines to your manifest.xml

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: it will work beacuse we are using this as standard one for all devices suppose if u want u can also add extra layouts

Comment: <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

Comment: yeah anywhere,, ucan put it above application tag

Comment: Thanks its working .But in emulator it doesn't reflected changes are made in device only.

Comment: k fine press ctrl+f12 to orientation changes in emulator

Answer (score 2):

```
Add This code in XML file before compiling the app
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```